# Linker command failed with exit code 1, XCode 4.5, Facebook SDK 3.1

Tags: xcode4.5, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook SDK into my xcode project, and I've sort of hit a stumbling point.

After some research, I tried making sure I had the latest version of the FacebookSDK, as those who had the same errors as I were able to resolve their issues with the latest version, but that did not help, so I tried downloading the source code from github and using the build_all.sh command to recompile, which also did not help.

I'll have the full error log be at the end because it's super long, but here is the part at the end:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've seen plenty of strings related to this issue but as I stated previously, neither updating to the latest SDK (an unnecessary step in my case as I already had it) or recompiling the source code for armv7, armv7s fixed the issue.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Full Error Log:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._delegate in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._url in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._connection in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._responseText in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._error in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._state in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBRequest._sessionDidExpire in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBRequest in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBRequest.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLoginDialog._loginDelegate in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBLoginDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLoginDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLoginDialog in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBLoginDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLoginDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBLoginDialog in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBLoginDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLoginDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._orientation in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._webView in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._modalBackgroundView in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity->iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._loadingURL in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._frictionlessSettings in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._delegate in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._showingKeyboard in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._closeButton in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._spinner in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._params in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._serverURL in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBDialog._isViewInvisible in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBDialog in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBDialog in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBDialog.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBDialog.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings._enabled in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings._allowedRecipients in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings._activeRequest in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._requests in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._lastAccessTokenUpdate in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._frictionlessRequestSettings in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._fbDialog in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._appId in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._urlSchemeSuffix in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._isExtendingAccessToken in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Facebook._sessionDelegate in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Facebook in:
>       /Users/tomhenry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bioesylflkyylfdprjpcoipvoxpb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Facebook.o
>       /Users/tomhenry/Facebook/build/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Facebook.o)
>   ld: 41 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656146/apple-mach-o-linker-errorduplicate-symbols-for-architecture-armv7/27004034#27004034

Answer (score 0):

you are missing framework for social networking, add it in your link with binary libraries of build phases in targets.

Comment: I've never heard of error "duplicate symbols" caused by missing linkage of another framework.